# Envío de valores numéricos cliente - servidor (Socket)

Tags: java

tengo un problema al enviar valores numeros de mi servidor al cliente. El socket del cliente lo guardo en un ArrayList, puedo conectar varios clientes. Mi for envia valores numericos random pero hasta que termine con el socketCliente1 por ejemplo sigue con el siguiente socketCliente2, si me pudieran ayudar se los agradeceria mucho...

```
    public void generarNumeroRandom() {
    for (int i = 0; i < arregloNumeroAleatorio.length; i++) {
        int numeroAleatorio = (int) (Math.random() * 25 + 1);
        arregloNumeroAleatorio[i] = numeroAleatorio;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (arregloNumeroAleatorio[i] == arregloNumeroAleatorio[j]) {
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
}

    public void enviarNumeroAleatorioCliente() throws InterruptedException {

    generarNumeroRandom();        
    for (Socket listaJugadoresConectados : listaJugadores) {
        try {
            DataOutputStream salidaDos = new DataOutputStream(listaJugadoresConectados.getOutputStream());
            for (int i = 0; i < arregloNumeroAleatorio.length; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                salidaDos.writeUTF(String.valueOf(arregloNumeroAleatorio[i]));
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HiloServidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No me quedó claro el problema.

Comment: El problema en si es este, el cliente2 se tiene que esperar a que el cliente1 visualice todos los números aleatorios, como hago para ir visualizando los números aleatorios al mismo tiempo tanto en cliente1 y cliente2, sin tener que esperar que cliente1 los visualice primero.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que quieres lograr necesita concurrencia, eso es, usar múltiples hilos para que los números se envíen en paralelo.

Agrega una clase miembro como esta:

```
class DespachadorDeNumerosConcurrente extends Thread {
        private DataOutputStream salidaDos;
        public DespachadorDeNumerosConcurrente(DataOutputStream salidaDos) {
            this.salidaDos = salidaDos;
        }

        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < arregloNumeroAleatorio.length; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                salidaDos.writeUTF(String.valueOf(arregloNumeroAleatorio[i]));
            }
        }

    }
```

La clase hereda de `Thread` y recibe en su constructor el socket del cliente al que se le enviarán los datos. En el método `run()` está el proceso de envío.

En el método `enviarNumeroAleatorioCliente()` reemplaza el código:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arregloNumeroAleatorio.length; i++) {
     Thread.sleep(5000);
     salidaDos.writeUTF(String.valueOf(arregloNumeroAleatorio[i]));
}
```

Por:

```
new DespachadorDeNumerosConcurrente(salidaDos).start();
```